# Does roasted garlic leave no aftertaste and smell

Tags: garlic, smell

I saw in a recipe book by the Grill company Weber where they claimed that if you roast a garlic over medium heat in the grill, until it becomes pulp, and then slather it on your baguette and eat it, it will not leave bad taste/smell afterwards.

Is this true? I love garlic but it leaves strong smell, so I avoid it.

Comment: Another option is to heat the garlic in warm milk for about 5 mins and then have the garlic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roasting garlic tends to make it sweeter and milder in flavour yes. It will not be completely undetectable, but it is certainly less strong than sautéed garlic.

Comment: It is less strong, but if you slather it on you will still repel vampires pretty effectively.